# 68k understading EQU X+$10

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

Let's say I have this 2 lines of code:

```
    ORG $8100
X   DC  1,2,3,4,5,...
EX  EQU X+$10
```

What does `X+$10` mean?
(On motorola 68000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` indicates a hexadecimal constant, in this case 10 hex, or 16 decimal. So

```
EX  EQU X+$10
```

means that the `EX` variable is defined to be 16 more than the `X` variable.

In this example, `X` happens to be 8100 hex and so `EX` would be 8110 hex.

Comment: to indicate a value shouldn't it be `#$16` ?

Comment: No, `#` is for immediate constant operands

Comment: @yes123 Thanks for fixing my typo, I should probably have stuck to using hex throughout ;-)